# Excel - Advanced Sorting Function

Tags: function, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a tournament spreadsheet that has a list of names in column "D" (between 20 and 150 entries) and the table number that each person is assigned to (column "E").

[image: See here...]

In column "I", I have a ridiculous formula that creates a list of the number of seats available at each table (this information changes from one event to another).

Column "G" is my problem. I want to run through the contents of column "E" and anytime there is a value in column "E" that matches the contents of column "I", to give the the contents of column "D".

[image: See here...]

Here is my formula as it currently stands in cell G3:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(D$3:D$150,SMALL(IF(E$3:E$150=I3,ROW(E$3:E$150)-ROW(E$3)+1),ROWS(E$3:E3))),"")}
```

The formula works perfectly for all values in column "E" as long as the value in column "E" is 1. This formula works beautifully in Google Sheets but Excel seems to process the ranges differently. I've tried with both a standard formula and an array formula without success.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

One additional note, I can use VBA if needed but I would prefer to stick with functions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

for this example I used the following formula:

```
=INDEX($C$14:$C$25,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$14:$D$25)-ROW($D$14)+1)/($D$14:$D$25=H16),COUNTIF($H$16:H16,H16)),1)
```

You will need to adjust the ranges to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, the problem appears to be with the `ROWS(E$3:E3)` as the second argument for the `SMALL` function. Basically, when you get down to your first 2 in row 12, you are asking the small function for the 10th smallest value in D that has 2 in column E. Since it looks like you are only expecting eight players, this will never find anything.

Try changing `ROWS(E$3:E3)` to `COUNTIF(I$3:I3, I3)`.

That will count how many 1's or 2's you've already passed in column I, so when you get to the 2's, it should reset and ask for the first smallest.

Answer (score 0):

@Forward Ed. Thanks for your input. That helped get me on the path that I needed.

Here is the formula that ended up working for me:

{=IFERROR(INDEX(D$3:D$150,SMALL(IF(E$3:E$150=I3,ROW(E$3:E$150)-MIN(ROW(E$3:E$150))+1),J3)),"")}